# React Router 1.0 Multiple <route/>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can add multiple root routes? My login page's html structure is completely different than other Authenticated Pages(DashBoard, managesubscription, etc.)

I created login.jsx somthing like as follows:-

```
var React = require('react');

var Login = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Login',
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div>Login</div>
            <form>
                User Name: <input type="text" name="username"/>
                Password<input type="password" name="password"/>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

module.exports = Login;
```

Router.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={History}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('tstdiv'));
```

app.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

How can i create AuthenticatedApp.jsx(for dashboard,managesubscription) like as following?

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

var AuthenticatedApp = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
            <Header/>
                {this.props.children}
            <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AuthenticatedApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to change your App.jsx into something like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Header = require('path/to/header');
var Footer = require('path/to/footer');

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        if (this.props.location.pathname === '/login') {
             Header = null; 
             Footer = null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Basically if it's the login page, we hide the header and footer, in every other case (the authenticated pages) will display the header and footer.

However I have a feeling that there is another way of doing this by changing how the routes are set up, so we can remove the if condition in this render.